# UIPickerview For Drop Down Menu

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4.2, uipickerview

I have Xcode 4.2 and I am trying to create a drop down menu. I would like the drop down menu to drop down with words or numbers. Then when I select something from the list I would like it to appear in a table on a different page. My question is: how would I write this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First create a UIViewController subclass with a nib file by going File > New > New File and following the prompts.

[image: Select UIViewController subclass]

[image: Name your class]

Now open the nib (MyViewController.xib).

[image: MyViewController.xib]

You should drag a UIPickerView and a UITableView into the view and arrange them however you like (it doesn't matter).

[image: UITableView]

[image: UIPickerView]

[image: Arrange the interface elements]

Next open the header file (MyViewController.h) for your UIViewController subclass.

[image: MyViewController.h]

At the end of the

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {
```

line add `<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>` so it looks like this

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>
```

Next you will need to add references to your tableview and picker and also two arrays of values. Just above `@end` add the following lines

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView* tableView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView* pickerView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray* tableData;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray* pickerData;
```

[image: MyViewController.h should look like this]

Then just go back to your nib file and connect the UITableView and UIPickerView to these variables.

[image: Connect your components]

Now in your source file (MyViewController.m) you need to synthesize you references. So add `@synthesize tableView, pickerView, tableData, pickerData` to the file just below `@implementation MyViewController`

[image: MyViewController.m]

Now to add the delegate methods, there will be quite a few of them, but they're pretty self explanatory.

The delegate methods for the UITableView are

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView*)tableView;

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;

- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

The delegate methods for the UIPickerView are

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView;

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component;

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component;

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component;
```

They should be added to the source file and used as follows

UITableView:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView*)tableView {
    // The number of sections in the UITableView
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // The number of rows in the UITableView
    return [tableData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Set the table cell text to the appropriate value in tableData
    cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Whatever happens when you select a table view row.
}
```

UIPickerView:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView;
{
    // The number of sections in the UIPickerView
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component;
{
    // The number of rows in the UIPickerView
    return [pickerData count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component;
{
    // The data for each row in the UIPickerView
    return [pickerData objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    // whatever you want to happen when a row is selected.

    // here I am assuming you want to remove from the picker and add to the table on selection
    [tableData addObject:[pickerData objectAtIndex:row]];
    [pickerData removeObjectAtIndex:row];

    [tableView reloadData];
    [pickerView reloadAllComponents];
}
```

[image: MyViewController should have these methods.]

Ok, the final thing you have to do is set the delegates and initialise the data. In the `- (void)viewDidLoad` method of `MyViewController` add the following lines

```
tableView.delegate = self;
tableView.dataSource = self;
pickerView.delegate = self;
pickerView.dataSource = self;

tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; // table starts empty
pickerData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", nil]; // picker starts with values 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

[tableView reloadData];
[pickerView reloadAllComponents];
```

[image: - (void)viewDidLoad should look like this.]

There are a few more delegate methods which you can find in the spec for the classes but these ones should be adequate for now.

Comment: hi there null0pointer thanks for this buddy will this work in a tabbed application or not because i need it for tabbed :/

Comment: and all so i have tried following the code and my lost I'm very new to Xcode and can't seem to find out where everything is and it just confuses me can you upload a image of the uipickerview etc and tell me which code is where .h - .m etc i really do appreciate it.

Comment: So I updated the post with a few images to help you locate things. I also fixed a couple of bugs I had in the code. Hope that helps.